# Common elements in python lists

Tags: python, list

I have lists of the following structure:
structure of the list: `[(id,start, end), (id,start, end), (id,start, end)]`

For example they could look like this:

```
List1 = [(1,50,56),(1,61,69),(1,70,87),(1,90,99),(1,110,117),(1,119,126),(2,3,9), (2,11,17), (3,2,9)]
List2 = [(1,44,56),(1,59,64),(1,70,81),(1,84,90),(1,99,155), (2,5,15), (3,3,9)]
```

I need to find overlapping regions between both of them.

I have tried the brute force method with this code:

```
for a1, s1, e1 in List1:
 for a2, s2, e2 in List2:
    sgroup = [s1, s2]
    egroup = [e1, e2]    
    mstart = max(sgroup)
    mend = min(egroup)
    if a1 == a2 and e2>=s1 and s2<=e1:
        t = (mstart, mend)
        print(t)
```

Can anyone help me speed this up? I need an algorithm to work faster than this brute method.

Comment: Output for this example please

Comment: What is the range of the possible values for start, end? if they're not prohibitively large (in your example nothing goes over 200), you could make an index of every single value. Or you could read an algorithms book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... this is extreme overkill here (I was having fun, leave me alone!), but it runs about 3x faster than the simple algorithm.

The real strength of this approach is it can handle very large lists without slowing down as much, and doesn't hold anything in memory. So try this with lists with 100 or 1000 things in them and you should see a bigger improvement.

I'm not assuming that the lists are sorted, so time should be dominated by the sort `O(n.log(n))` assuming Pythons sorting algorithm is good.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


def get_list_overlaps(list_a, list_b):
    for range_id, (a_ranges, b_ranges) in align_lists(list_a, list_b):
        a_range = next(a_ranges)
        b_range = next(b_ranges)

        try:
            while a_range and b_range:
                overlap = get_overlap(a_range, b_range)
                if overlap:
                    yield overlap

                    # If we overlap, discard the one which ends earliest
                    if a_range[2] < b_range[2]:
                        a_range = next(a_ranges)
                    else:
                        b_range = next(b_ranges)

                else:
                    # If not, discard the one which starts earliest
                    if a_range[1] < b_range[1]:
                        a_range = next(a_ranges)
                    else:
                        b_range = next(b_ranges)

    except StopIteration:
            continue

def align_lists(list_a, list_b):
    b_grouped = groupby(sorted(list_b), key=itemgetter(0))
    b_id, b_intervals = next(b_grouped)

    for a_id, a_intervals in groupby(sorted(list_a), key=itemgetter(0)):
        # Work until our lists line up
        if a_id < b_id:
            continue

        try:
            while a_id > b_id:
                b_id, b_intervals = next(b_grouped)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        yield a_id, (a_intervals, b_intervals)


def get_overlap(a_range, b_range):
    _, a_start, a_end = a_range
    _, b_start, b_end = b_range

    # If either ends before the other starts, no overlap
    if b_end < a_start or a_end < b_start:
        return

    return max(a_start, b_start), min(a_end, b_end)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------- #

List1 = [(1, 50, 56), (1, 61, 69), (1, 70, 87), (1, 90, 99), (1, 110, 117),
     (1, 119, 126), (2, 3, 9), (2, 11, 17), (3, 2, 9)]
List2 = [(1, 44, 56), (1, 59, 64), (1, 70, 81), (1, 84, 90), (1, 99, 155),
     (2, 5, 15), (3, 3, 9)]

for overlap in get_list_overlaps(List1, List2):
    print(overlap)
```

The idea is to group by the id first, so we never bother comparing things with different ids, and then slide through the things in each id, throwing things out when the do and don't overlap.

You could probably optimise this by inlining some of the functions etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
for a1, s1, e1 in List1:
    for a2, s2, e2 in List2:
        if a1 == a2 and s2 <= e1 and e2 >= s1:
            print (max(s1, s2), min(e1, e2))
```

#### [EDIT]: Measuring times:

```
import time 

def group1():
    res = []
    for a1, s1, e1 in List1:
        for a2, s2, e2 in List2:
            sgroup = [s1, s2]
            egroup = [e1, e2]    
            mstart = max(sgroup)
            mend = min(egroup)
            if a1 == a2 and e2>=s1 and s2<=e1:
                t = (mstart, mend)
                res.append(t)
    return res

def group2():
    res = []
    for a1, s1, e1 in List1:
        for a2, s2, e2 in List2:
            if a1 == a2 and s2 <= e1 and e2 >= s1:
                res.append((max(s1, s2), min(e1, e2)))
    return res

List1 = [(1,50,56),(1,61,69),(1,70,87),(1,90,99),(1,110,117),(1,119,126),(2,3,9), (2,11,17), (3,2,9)]
List2 = [(1,44,56),(1,59,64),(1,70,81),(1,84,90),(1,99,155), (2,5,15), (3,3,9)]

for func in [group1, group2]:
    start = time.time()
    func()
    end = time.time()
    print(f'{func.__name__}: {end - start}')
    print(func())
```

#### output:

```
group1: 6.985664367675781e-05
group2: 1.9788742065429688e-05
```

Comment: This version of the code might be a bit cleaner, but it's not faster. The question is about optimizing the code.

Comment: Should be faster, all this sgroup, egroup mstart mend calculation is not performed if there is no overlap.

Comment: @SimonLandry paul has a point, by nesting the calculations within the `if` statement the times should improve because they are only performed in the case where the `if` statement is true (a small percentage of the time)! @paul should change `s2 < e1` to `s2 <= e1` though as OP has it, same with the `e2 > s1` bit

Comment: See list comprehension answer below which appears to faster than the double loop answers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're already guaranteed that your lists are sorted by ID and start time, and have no overlaps.  Essentially, each ID is a separate list for overlap detection.

You will progress through the pair of lists just as you would for a list merge (which this is, essentially).  Have an index into each list (index_a, index_b); at each iteration, you work with the lesser of the two referred values (the start value that's at the index).

To process one interval -- the element at list_a[index_a]:

- get its ending value.
- set check_b = index_b

  - compare this to the starting value of the item in the other list.
  - while end[index a] > start[check_b], then you have an overlap; report it.
  - Increment `check_b`.
- increment index_a.
- Check the new list_a item with the current list_b item; choose the one with the lower starting value, and return to the top of this process (first bullet).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with list comprehension you can do:

```
List1 = [(1,50,56),(1,61,69),(1,70,87),(1,90,99),(1,110,117),(1,119,126),(2,3,9), (2,11,17), (3,2,9)]                                                
List2 = [(1,44,56),(1,59,64),(1,70,81),(1,84,90),(1,99,155), (2,5,15), (3,3,9)]                                                                      

output = [(max(s1, s2), min(e1, e2)) for id1, s1, e1 in List1 
                                     for id2, s2, e2 in List2                                                               
                                     if id1 == id2 and e2 >= s1 and s2 <= e1]

print(output)
```

The output is:

```
[(50, 56), (61, 64), (70, 81), (84, 87), (90, 90), (99, 99), (110, 117), (119, 126), (5, 9), (11, 15), (3, 9)]
```

which appears to be the same answer as from the original.  Generally list comprehensions are going to be faster than standard loops.

List Comprehension: **6.51 µs** ± 13.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Original Loop: **25.2 µs** ± 239 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

("Original Loop" comparison code was:

```
    output = []
    for a1, s1, e1 in List1:
        for a2, s2, e2 in List2:
            sgroup = [s1, s2]
            egroup = [e1, e2]
            mstart = max(sgroup)
            mend = min(egroup)
            if a1 == a2 and e2>=s1 and s2<=e1:
                output.append((mstart, mend))
```

)

Answer (score 0):

A couple observations to note here:

1. ranges with different ids cannot overlap. This means that we can partition the problem based on the ids, and then solve each partition separately, ignoring the id.
2. If you sort the lists, then you don't need to check all ranges against all ranges, instead, you can break early as soon as you see that e1 < s2. Also, if the distance between your end and start point are fairly short compared to the range of values they can take, you can also start skipping from List2.

What you are looking for here is a form of sliding window algorithm, not too dissimilar to what you'd see in TCP.

Therefore, putting it all together:

```
from itertools import groupby

List1 = [(1,50,56),(1,61,69),(1,70,87),(1,90,99),(1,110,117),(1,119,126),(2,3,9), (2,11,17), (3,2,9)]
List2 = [(1,44,56),(1,59,64),(1,70,81),(1,84,90),(1,99,155), (2,5,15), (3,3,9)]

def partition(lst):
    part = groupby(lst, lambda el: el[0])
    return {id: list(el) for id, el in part}

# you may be able to skip sorted() here if you know your input is already sorted
List1_part = partition(sorted(List1))
List2_part = partition(sorted(List2))

for id in set(List1_part) & set(List2_part):
    window_size = max((e-s) for _, s, e in List2_part[id])
    window = 0
    for r1 in List1_part[id]:
        for r2 in List2_part[id][window:]:
            _, s1, e1 = r1
            _, s2, e2 = r2
            if e1 < s2:
                break
            elif e2 >= s1:
                print(id, max(s1, s2), min(e1, e2))
            elif s2 + window_size < s1: 
                window += 1
```